# Ionic registerBackButtonAction does not work

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a basic ionic project `ionic start test sidemenu`
2. Add the android platform `ionic platform add android`
3. In **app.js** add the code:

   ```
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) { 
       alert("back button action handler");            
       event.preventDefault(); 
    }, 999);
   ```

   This code can be added in the .run method or in the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` method - same result, not working
4. `ionic build android` then `ionic upload` -> or manually put the APK on a device

[BUG]
 - the alert is not shown and history view navigation is performed. It's like this action that I try to register is not taken into consideration.

What am I doing wrong? I tried this code in a controller also, also `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.stopImmediatePropagation` still no success.

I have the latest Ionic (1.4.5) and Cordova 4.3.0, tested on some Samsung devices. In Ripple, it works ok.

Comment: Try listening for this event using document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {alert('backbutton detected')}, false);

Comment: It might not work but that is the event that Ionic is wrapping so it should get fired.

Comment: If I use document.addEventListener('backbutton', ......) it works, but I don't have access to the ionic services in that callback to check the current state name, check the history, to add a condition to perform a back in the history or ionic.Platform.exitApp() depending on the state.

Comment: Did you try another number aside 999? like 100? (return to previous view)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Are you including $ionicPlatform in the .run() function? I am doing exactly your example and it works

Comment: I tried this a few months ago. Perhaps now it works. I tried afterwards and it was a difference in app behavior if I install the file automatically on the phone or I run the app from IonicView

Comment: Works well for me, but I call the $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction inside my controller init() method. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

try preventing the default first

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("back button action handler");  
 }, 999);
```

Also the code 999 is perfectly valid, the codes 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 are just the priorities that ionic asigns to certain actions of the back button. I've used multiple times the priority 900, it just puts your backbutton on top of all other action.

More information in the documentation : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use code 999?
Here that info about 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, but not 900.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/

I use code for example 501 and this works.

That is example from my project which works

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function () {
            $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(registerBackButtonAction, 501);
        });

  function registerBackButtonAction(e) {

            if (!!e && typeof e.preventDefault === 'function') {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            // some code

            return false;
        }
```